# Why is this deforming?

Tags: modeling

Im new to Blender.

I have created a shape with a 'Circle Mesh' and am trying to use the curve modifier to curve the shape around a 'Circle Curve'.

When I do this it deforms it. Is there any way to add the horizontal and vertical lines?

Should I be creating this shape with a different mesh?

[image]

Comment: hello, you say that you want to curve your object then complain that it deforms? it's not clear what you're trying to achieve, could you please show a picture of what you would like to achieve?

Comment: Hey Moonboots! I want the shape to curve around the cylinder but have the face of the extrusion remain flat.

Comment: Welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem may easily find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*","*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, answers you get depend heavily on how inviting it is. See ["*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Have you tried changing the orientation of the shape? Could it be Blender doesn't know what face you're actually trying to make follow the curve?

Comment: Thank you guys for the replies! I ended up creating a plane with lots of subdivisions and just deleted the vertices outside of the shape. It now keeps its geometry around the curve WOOOHOOOO

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a plane with lots of subdivisions and just deleted the vertices outside of the shape. It now keeps its geometry around the curve.